# Discord.js how to find out how many servers a virgo bot is on

Tags: discord.js

With Discord.js, how can I check how many servers another bot whose id is specified is on?
(I'm using google translate it might be a typo)

I tried with the client.users.cache.get() function, but this data is not there.

Comment: You do not have access to another bot's data

Answer (score 0):

I think that will work :

```js
client.users.cache.size
```

If it don't work, read this page on the documentation : [Client Class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the amount of guilds another bot is on, but you can click on the invite link of the bot and it should say the amount of servers it's on:

[image]